# Negative weights for `roc_auc_score`

Tags: scikit-learn

I find that the `roc_auc_score` function sometimes breaks when I have negative values in `sample_weight`. How can I plot the roc curve as well as compute the AUC?

Is it a bug ?

```
ValueError: x is neither increasing nor decreasing :
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a problem of how ROC AUC is calculated in sklearn. It calculates it directly as the area under the ROC curve, but when you have negative weights the ROC curve can get loops, which makes it multivalued.

I developed some code to calculate ROC AUC as the probability of correct ordering of randomly sampled pairs of classes - such approach allows for negative weights. Check out [this repository](https://github.com/SiLiKhon/my_roc_auc).

*Edit*

> How can I plot the roc curve

If you want to plot the curve, you can calculate FPR and TPR manually as a function of threshold. This will give you looped curves though.

Comment: Hi your solution gives similar results to a function I wrote to calculate the AUC manually for negative weights. Could you explain a bit what you are doing? The code is difficult to understand without comments

Comment: Sure. I'm relying here on the fact that, as [wikipedia states it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Receiver_operating_characteristic#Area_under_the_curve), AUC "is equal to the probability that a classifier will rank a randomly chosen positive instance higher than a randomly chosen negative one". My code is calculating this probability. If we ignore the `correction` calculation, basically, I'm taking all possible pairs of `(class0_prediction, class1_prediction)` pairs and calculate the weighted fraction of those that satisfy `class0_prediction <= class1_prediction`, i.e. ordered correctly.

Comment: Now, the `correction` term is to account for the cases when `class0_prediction == class1_prediction`, as you have to take such pairs into account with only 1/2 of their weight.

Comment: That's a very interesting way of doing it, bypassing the need to calculate area